# No connector for [] rabbitmq queue

Tags: laravel-5.7

I try run a queue in Rabbitmq.But it gives me No connectors Found[] error. How to resolve this?

I installed driver using composer require vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

I have this in my .env file

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=emails

RABBITMQ_HOST=127.0.0.1
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_VHOST=/
RABBITMQ_LOGIN=guest
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
Problem is in .env file 
add QUEUE_CONNECTION=rabbitmq
and in queue.php make  'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'rabbitmq'),